# Run C++ executable on PHP

Tags: php, c++, linux, executable

I want to write PHP script, which executes C++ executable on Linux machine. I use exec() or system() PHP functions. But it doesn't execute C++ executable. 
My code is the following. Proc is compiled C++ executable. Exactly the same command works fine in the shell.

```
echo system('/var/www/image_proc/proc "/var/www/image_proc/images/original/5_1.png" 70 0 0 "/var/www/image_proc/images/processed/5_2.png"');
```

I checked all permissions for executing and writing files. And I am using absolute paths to be sure that it is not a path problem.

Is anyone know, what could be a problem?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you seeing errors? Or do you just not see the output you expect?

Comment: Does the following work? <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); echo system("ls"); ?> If not, does it display anything?

Comment: is there some flags, that i have to add in php.ini to execute C++ script?

Comment: If you're using PHP <5.4.0, you might want to check if [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) is enabled. If it is, you'll need to add `/var/www/image_proc` to [sage-mode-exec-dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir).

Comment: since ls worked... are you sure the user under which apache is running has execution rights? i know you said you checked, just saying to double check :)

Comment: @Kamar good. Please try the following then: <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); echo system("/var/www/image_proc/proc"); ?> Does it output any error, or does it work?

Comment: send the output to a file: `echo system('/var/www/image_proc/proc "/var/www/image_proc/images/original/5_1.png" 70 0 0 "/var/www/image_proc/images/processed/5_2.png" > /var/www/myfile.out');`

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Still could not find a problem. I haven't get any error. Safe_mode is off and all file permissions are set to 777. I tried to write output to the file, but it is empty. The return code of system function is 127.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is the use of quotes. The SHELL might expand/evaluate these, but a call to system() will not. [libc system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

The suggested solution is therefore:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $src = "/var/www/image_proc/images/original/5_1.png";
    $dst = "/var/www/image_proc/images/processed/5_2.png";
    $cmd = sprintf("/var/www/image_proc/proc %s 70 0 0 %s", $src, $dst);
    $result = system($cmd, $retval);
    printf("Result: '%s'\n\nReturn value: %d\n\n", $result, $retval);
?>
```

This will either output the result of the command, or a useful error info. Especially important is that this gives us a return value based on which we can find out what happened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried also this, but still the same problem, the return code is 127, which means that system() cannot find executable, but the path is correct and the command works fine in shell.

Comment: @Karmar This means the path is invalid. More precisely, PHP cannot see that path. Apache may be running in a chroot'ed or otherwise secured environment which prevents it from reading /var/www/image_proc OR (less likely reason) adding the arguments causes your command to fail. I suggest to take it from here and run chdir("/var/www/image_proc"); foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    echo $filename . "<br />\n";
} Does it output all files in /var/www/image_proc? If not, it's the chroot / security case. // the glob must contain star-dot-star (*.*). For some reason, it's not showing up properly.

Comment: @Kamar after answering this question, I should be able to tell you how to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Marek. I found a problem. When running C++ executable from browser (by executing "php phpfilename" in command file, it worked ), it couldn't find shared libraries that was need for the C++ file. The reason was, the environment variable that I set for shared libraries, was not set for apache user. I set it in php via putenv function and that solves my problem.

Comment: @Kamar Great, I'm glad it works. May I get at least thumbs up? (one vote) :)